# How to view/edit the source code of a wizarddialog in Eclipse

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, eclipse-plugin

I am not so familiar with Eclipse plugin. I have one question on viewing/editing source code of a  wizard dialog in Eclipse.

For example: In Eclipse, click File ->New->Class, the "New Java Class" wizard dialog appears.

My question is:

1. How to view the source code of this wizard dialog?
2. Can I modify the style of this wizard dialog? For example, the default value for "Superclass" is `java.lang.Object`, can I change the default value to another class(e.g. com.myown.myaction)?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to view the source code of wizardDialog in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392852/how-to-view-the-source-code-of-wizarddialog-in-eclipse)

Comment: Nope, not a duplicate. The other question is about opening the sources of the WizardDialog, this one is about finding a sub-class of WizardDialog currently shown on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

To quickly view a source of a UI element use Plug-in Selection Spy tool (press Alt+Shift+F1 on a selected UI element). Then if you know the class and plug-in it originate from you can import it into your workspace and browse.

Comment: One might have to properly enable target platform and configure Java search for that to work.